# Setup.py ... breaks when name and py_modules are different

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to get an in depth understanding of a bare minimum python package.  As a setup.py this works perfectly:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='helloworld',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Say hello!',
    py_modules=['helloworld'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
)
```

Again, I can import and run "helloworld" just fine.  However, when I change "name" and "py_modules" to be something different from each other the system breaks.  According to Mark Smith's [EuroPython lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WDV0-OB4fE) "name" is what you pip install and "py_modules" is what you import.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='installMe',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Say hello!',
    py_modules=['importMe'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
)
```

So I installed the software in a python virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv bareMinEnv
source bareMinEnv/bin/activate
pip install -e .
```

and everything looked fine:

```
pip list
Package    Version Location
---------- ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------
installMe  0.0.1   /mnt/d/PROJECTS/PACKAGE_CREATION/min2/bareMinimumPythonPackage/src
pip        20.2.3
setuptools 49.2.1
```

However, it breaks at the importation step.  Here it show's I can't import "importMe":

```
>>> from importMe import say_hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importMe'
```

and here is evidence I can't import "installMe":

```
>>> from installMe import say_hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'installMe'
```

All of this works if I keep the names the same.   So how to I make them different while maintaining functionality?  I've created a dozen packages and I don't understand why it's not behaving as I believe the documentation describes.  Again, this is easy to fix by keeping the names the same. However, I'm trying to understand every detail about the pip packaging system.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you install your package? `pip install .` from your root development directory?

Comment: See also https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#py-modules . Which indicates this is for modules that you ship with the package, but don't belong to the package. `six` is given as a clear example of that: it's a simple module that helps a whole bunch of packages work, but isn't really it's part of any of such packages (since it is its own package).

Comment: But why do you want the package name to be different upon import than upon shipping or development?

Comment: I updated the post.  I installed the package in a python virtual environment with "pip install -e ."  I'm tying to get an in depth understanding of python packaging.  I don't "need" to have the names different, but I want to understand what's going on.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the contents of `src`? When you specify `py_modules=['importMe']`, you are saying there should be a file called `importMe.py` under `src`. If there isn't, this doesn't seem to crash the install. It does it you use packages (which means guaranteeing `importMe/__init__.py` exists). That might be a bug.

Comment: I got it working, thanks.  I didn't realize it was one python file per module.  I thought that since we were pointing it to the src directory, it would use all of those files under whatever module name we gave it.  This makes sense now.  Thanks!